# can we generate loss curve for mlpregressor with lbfgs solver

Tags: python, regression

is it possible to generate loss curve for MLPregressor with lbfgs solver? it has been specified that it can be generated only for 'adam' solver.

if it can be done, kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

You can plot `model.loss_curve_` on your dataframe, and you're good to go!

Comment: Would you explain how this can be used regarding the question on "lbfgs" solver? I do not understand this part of your answer.

Comment: model.loss_curve_ works only with the default solver 'adam' , not in lbfgs